# ¿Por qué no funciona mi modo nocturno con local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Quiero guardar en localStorage el estado de mi "dark mode", pero no logro dar con ello. La función enableDark almacena ("darkMode", "on"/"off") en localStorage (eso funciona bien) pero luego al refrescar la página no parece funcionar. El código que falla es el siguiente:

```
function retrieveDarkStatus(){
    if (localStorage.getItem(("darkMode")==="on")){
        darkStatus=true;
        enableDark();
    }else {
        darkStatus=false;
    }
}
retrieveDarkStatus();
```

La función enableDark es la siguiente y parece funcionar bien:

```
function enableDark(){
    body.classList.toggle("dark");
    if(darkStatus==false){
        console.log("Oh, it's getting dark..");
        darkStatus=true;
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "on");
    }else{
        console.log("Sun is up!");
        darkStatus=false;
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "off" );
    }
}
```

Alguno ve cual es la falta? No puedo usar jQuery, por las dudas. Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

¿Es porque haces `if (localStorage.getItem("darkMode"==="on"))` en vez de `if (localStorage.getItem("darkMode")==="on")`?

Échale un vistazo a [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

UPDATE:

Aquí tienes un pequeño problema con la manera en que implementas esto, porque por ejemplo, en:

```
function enableDark(){
    body.classList.toggle("dark");
    if(darkStatus==false){
        console.log("Oh, it's getting dark..");
        darkStatus=true;
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "on");
    }else{
        console.log("Sun is up!");
        darkStatus=false;
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "off" );
    }
}
```

Estás cambiando el valor de la variable `darkStatus`... Pero al mismo tiempo ¿Preguntas por el valor que tiene? Mira estás tres líneas de código:

```
if(darkStatus==false){
        console.log("Oh, it's getting dark..");
        darkStatus=true;
```

Preguntas por `darkstatus` para saber si es falso y luego asignas la variable a `true` lo cuál es redundante porque siempre va a ser `true`e igual no estás tomando en cuenta para hacer un cambio de estilo en tu página porque estás directamente haciendo `body.classList.toggle("dark");`.

Yo creo que si tienes una variable para manejar el modo `dark` (en localStorage) deberías de cambiar esa variable por medio de la función `enableDark()` y podrías tener otra función para updatear el estilo del cuerpo con respecto a ese valor cuando sea necesario o esta variable cambie... Algo así:

```js
//Usas esta función para cambiar el modo: dark o light mode
function setDark(valor) {
  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", valor ? "on" : "off");
}

//Usas esta para actualizar el estilo de tu página en base a la variable darkStatus
function updateDarkMode() {
  if (retrieveDarkStatus()) {
    console.log("Oh, it's getting dark..");
    body.classList.toggle("dark");
  } else {
    console.log("Sun is up!");
    //body.classList.toggle("light");
  }
}

//Esta función verifica el estado de tu variable guardada en memoria
function retrieveDarkStatus() {
  return localStorage.getItem(("darkMode") === "on");
}
```

Comment: Perdón fue un error de tipeo, está bien esa sintaxis pero igual no funciona.

Comment: En ese caso te sugiero que compartas el código en dónde haces referencia a la variable `darkStatus` porque pareciese que el error está en como implementas el cambio al modo dark.

Comment: Gracias Fran, ahí agregué la función a la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema con el código era un paréntesis de más. Estaba escrito así:

```
if (localStorage.getItem((“darkMode”)==“on”)){
```

debería haber sido:

```
if (localStorage.getItem(“darkMode”)==“on”){
```

Gracias!